# Can we have a tabbed pane at the bottom of the page in a Lightning component?

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

[image: A Page]

I am developing a  Sales force Lightning Application.I am wondering if we can develop a Tabbed pane at the bottom of a page similar to the image you see at the top.

The image has a Tabbed Pane at the bottom .

I am trying to embed this pane at the bottom of each page/ we develop through Lightning components in Salesforce Lightning.

Comment: you want chatter feed at the bottom of each page?

Comment: Yes Exactly ! or similiar to that

Comment: i don't think that`s natively possible you have to write custom logic for this.